# MYSQL - Combining two LEFT JOIN statements through UNION ALL but keeping the columns intact

Tags: mysql, sql

DB Structure

```
customer 
---------
accountID
(other tuples not needed in this problem)

rental
-------
accountID
videoID

previousrental
-------
accountID
videoID
```

I am trying to write a query that shows accountID along with previous and current rentals.
I'd want the final table to show something along the lines of

```
| accountID |   videorented    |    videorentals  |
|-----------|------------------|------------------|
|   123     |       9987       |       NULL       |
|   123     |       9233       |       NULL       |
|   123     |       NULL       |       9987       |
|   101     |       9987       |       NULL       |
|   123     |       1589       |       NULL       |
|   123     |       NULL       |       8888       |
|   444     |       NULL       |       NULL       |
```

I came up with something along the lines of creating two left joins that that are able to correctly show the accountID along with which videos they have/are renting/rented and now I want to combine the two LEFT JOINS while keeping the single accountID column but also having videorented and videorentals as separate columns.

I've tried using UNION and UNION ALL but this just combines videorented and videorentals into one column
I'm currently lost as to where to go from here

```
SELECT c.accountID, pr.videoID as videorented
FROM customer c
LEFT JOIN previousrental pr
ON c.accountID=pr.accountID
UNION
SELECT c.accountID, r.videoID as videorentals
FROM customer c
LEFT JOIN rental r
ON c.accountID = r.accountID
;
```

Comment: Consider this: first create a derived table from the union all of the current / past. Then join this: `.. from account a left join (select 1 as current, accountid, videoid from rental union all select 0 as current ..) r on r.accountid = a.accountid ..`

Comment: Anyway, it is unclear how “video rentals” should fit in if normalized (because it’s 0/1..N), and I suspect the table structure (and desired output) might benefit from being reconsidered..

Answer (score 0):

You could left join to customer twice.

```
SELECT DISTINCT
  cust.accountID
, prev.videoID as videorented
, rent.videoID as videorentals
FROM customer cust
CROSS JOIN (SELECT 1 num UNION SELECT 2) nums
LEFT JOIN previousrental prev
  ON prev.accountID = cust.accountID  AND num = 1
LEFT JOIN rental rent
  ON rent.accountID = cust.accountID AND num = 2
ORDER BY cust. accountID, COALESCE(prev.videoID, rent.videoID)
```

| accountID | videorented | videorentals |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 101 | *null* | *null* |
| 101 | 9987 | *null* |
| 123 | 1589 | *null* |
| 123 | *null* | 8888 |
| 123 | 9233 | *null* |
| 123 | 9987 | *null* |
| 123 | *null* | 9987 |
| 444 | *null* | *null* |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.5&fiddle=8f567b5a633c168d184309483f367c50)*